# JavaScript regex to limit number of characters and allow digits and no more than one letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regex that matches a string of digits and up to one letter (in any position), something like this:

```
^\d*[a-zA-Z]?\d*$
```

but the string must be between two and six characters long.

E.g. these would be valid:

```
12  
a1  
12B3  
B12345  
123C45  
12345g
```

but these would not be:

```
AB  
C123D
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is fairly close, you just need to add a lookahead condition in your regex:

```
^(?=.{2,6}$)\d*[a-zA-Z]?\d*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DIFlhL/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=.{2,6}$)`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have 2 to 6 characters ahead of start position
- `\d*`: Match 0 or more digits
- `[a-zA-Z]?`: Match an optional English letter
- `\d*`: Match 0 or more digits
- `$`: End

Comment: yes, it worked perfectly, thank you! I didn't know that positive lookaheads could be used that way.